# Remove all elements that are not of type int

Tags: python, list

But i get one or more elements in list that not of type int

```
class CyberList:

    def __init__(self, new_list):
        for i in new_list:
            if type(i) != int:
                new_list.remove(i)
        print(new_list)

CyberList([1, 2, '', [], 2, 'ggt', 'gg'])
```

I try to use metods remove(), pop(), but it doesn't help
List must include only int types

Comment: Why not [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)?

Comment: You shouldn't mutate a list while iterating over it. It will mess up the iteration index

Comment: This is a common pitfall in python that folks run into often. Namely, removing items from a list inside of a for loop, and the unexpected results of that operation. Check out [this very popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) about how to remove items from a list while iterating, properly.

Comment: Don't use `type()` use `isinstance(i, int)`

Comment: @JNevill Not just Python. It's common in every programming language with mutable collections, which includes virtually all mainstream programming languages.

Comment: Create a new list: `new_list=[x for x in [1, 2, '', [], 2, 'ggt', 'gg'] if type(x).__name__=='int']` if you specifically only want `int` or `new_list=[x for x in [1, 2, '', [], 2, 'ggt', 'gg'] if isinstance(x, int)]` if derivatives are OK.

Comment: @KonradRudolph for sure. This is a common problem even with folks iterating through rows in excel in VBA and deleting as they go. I think that question comes daily in the VBA tag for folks with the intestinal fortitude to follow that circus of a tag.